# Adding elements into a vector using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I have a 2-dimensional vector that I repeatedly add elements to. I know how to do it using nested for loops. However, I was wondering if there was a way to do it using recursion? Here is my code using loops:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int > >test;
    int items;
    cout<< "How many items" <<endl;
    cin>> items;

    for (int i = 0; i < items+1; i++) {
        vector<int> row; // Create an empty row

        for (int j = 0; j < items+1; j++) {
            row.push_back((i-1)+j); // Add an element(column) to the row
        }
        test.push_back(row);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < items+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < items+1; j++) {
            cout << setw(4)<<test[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to turn this into a recursive function?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want to do recursion for this when using loops is simpler, clearer, and better?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient especially if you get higher dimension vectors?

Comment: @Flux21 Most of the time you do not want to have a vector of vectors.  You should use a single vector and "fake" the dimensions by using math to convert a nD index into a 1D index.

Comment: Using recursion would introduce overhead in copying the vector between stack frames. It makes more sense to do this in a loop.

Comment: @tmsimont If you pass be reference then that should not be a problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point. At the very least, wouldn't you still be creating additional stack frames?

Comment: @tmsimont Yes unless the compiler can optimize the recursion away.  But I agree with you that the potential overhead involved with recursion is not needed when there is a nice easy iterative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
#include "iostream"
#include "iomanip"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

void insert (vector < vector <int> >& my_vector, int& items, vector <int>& row, int value, int index)
{
    if (row.size()==items) // check if row is complete
    {
        my_vector.push_back(row); // add row to 2D vector
        row.clear();
        if (index<items) 
            insert(my_vector, items, row, index+1, index+1); // for next row
    }
    else // row is not complete
    {
        row.push_back(value); // add element to row
        insert(my_vector, items, row, value+1, index); // for next element
    }
}

int main()
{
    int items;
    cout << "How many items? ";
    cin >> items;
    vector < vector <int> > my_vector;
    vector <int> row;
    insert(my_vector, items, row, 1, 1);
    for (auto i: my_vector)
    {
        for (auto j: i)
            cout << setw(4) << j;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// Programed by Scourge
// GNU GPLv3

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

// This is a good method because we can get all the files (with or without folder) recursive or not
// from a target directory, and then have all those elements placed into a vector for easy 'for'
// loop usage and functional parsing.

vector<string> scan_dir(string scan_start, string scope, string include_folder, vector<string> &vec_track){
    
    DIR *current_dir = opendir (scan_start.c_str()); // starting dir given as a string

    // "dir_item" can be anything in the "current_dir" such as a new folder, file, binary, etc.

    while (struct dirent *dir_item_ptr = readdir(current_dir)){
        string dir_item =  (dir_item_ptr->d_name); // structure points to the getter to retrive the dir_item's name.
        if (dir_item != "." and dir_item != "./" and dir_item != ".."){
            if (dir_item_ptr->d_type == DT_DIR){
                if(scope == "r" or scope == "-r"){
                    if(include_folder == "f" or include_folder == "-f"){
                        vec_track.push_back(dir_item);
                    }
                    scan_dir(scan_start + "/"+ dir_item, scope, include_folder, vec_track); // recursive function
                }
            }else if(dir_item == "read"){
                break; // full dir already read, leave the loop
            }else{
                vec_track.push_back(dir_item);
            }
        }
    }
    return vec_track;
    closedir (current_dir); 
}

int main(){

    vector<string> rec_vec;
    vector<string> pwd_vec;

    // './' as arg 1 sets the target folder to your PWD

    scan_dir("./","-r","-f", rec_vec); // "scope"          = '-r' =  target_folder recursive search
    // recursive vector from pwd       // "include_folder" = '-f' = include folders in the results

    scan_dir("./","-n","-n", pwd_vec); // "scope"          = '-n' = use target_folder but not recursive  
    // pwd vector                      // "include_folder  = '-n' = not folder included


    for(string& i: rec_vec){cout << i << endl;} // loop through and print the vector's elements
    cout << "---------------------\n";
    for(string& i: pwd_vec){cout << i << endl;} // loop through and print the vector's elements

    return 0;
}
```